# Processing time for a request using Jolokia

Tags: java, jmx, jolokia

I'm developping a Web Service, using Glassfish 4. When someone makes a call, I know how many time each method took. I'm saving this information on log(Log4J).

Now I want to monitorize the application using JMX (Currently I'm using Jolokia).

From what I know, there are 2 possibilities:

1. Implement Mbean interface and extends it on all my classes

   - Disadvantages: too much code and possible wasting memory and processing time)
2. Use JMXlogger (the information about this solution is very old)

Is there another strategy?